# Scalable grid of divs to fit browser size

Tags: jquery, css, scalability

I'm struggling to create a scalable grid of divs /  images that will adjust to the size of the browser, something like this: http://svla.co/

I don't know if it possible using CSS and may require jQuery, I'm not sure at all. Here's my code:

```
<div id="journal-overview">
    <a href="#"><div class="journal-thumbs" style="background-color: #f3f3f4; width: 315px; height: 196px"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="journal-thumbs" style="background-color: #f3f3f4; width: 315px; height: 196px"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="journal-thumbs" style="background-color: #f3f3f4; width: 315px; height: 196px"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="journal-thumbs" style="background-color: #f3f3f4; width: 315px; height: 196px"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="journal-thumbs" style="background-color: #f3f3f4; width: 315px; height: 196px"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="journal-thumbs" style="background-color: #f3f3f4; width: 315px; height: 196px"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="journal-thumbs" style="background-color: #f3f3f4; width: 315px; height: 196px"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="journal-thumbs" style="background-color: #f3f3f4; width: 315px; height: 196px"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="journal-thumbs" style="background-color: #f3f3f4; width: 315px; height: 196px"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="journal-thumbs" style="background-color: #f3f3f4; width: 315px; height: 196px"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="journal-thumbs" style="background-color: #f3f3f4; width: 315px; height: 196px"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="journal-thumbs" style="background-color: #f3f3f4; width: 315px; height: 196px"></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="journal-thumbs" style="background-color: #f3f3f4; width: 315px; height: 196px"></div></a>
</div>
```

and a jsfiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/KgpTT/ 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use percentage values and Media Queries.

Comment: Why would you need a jQuery library when you could just do it with javascript alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the new CSS flexbox capabilities, if the browsers you are targeting support it. It will handle this use case for breakfast, including not only re-layout but also dynamic re-sizing of the individual elements. See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/. It supports responsive design inherently. Your problem might be solved by something as simple as putting a `display: flex;` CSS property on your container. Even if you can't use it for this project, it's worth a look.

Comment: this looks good, thank you. I think my problem may be able to be solved quite easily though I'm just not sure how. Say I want a 4 column grid across all browser, thus each div being about 25% of the width. Is it not possible to scale the height and the widths proportionatly to my original size of 315x196?

Comment: Just add a CSS rule `.journal-thumbs { flex: 0 0 25%; }`. The `0 0` means that they neither grow nor shrink from their 25% starting width. Note that as of now you will have to prefix as `display: -webkit-flex;` (for the container) and `-webkit-flex: 0 0 25%;` (for the items).